# Find first and last documents matching a query?

Tags: mongodb

What's the most efficient way to find the first and last documents that match a query?  There are potentially a large number of documents that match the query.

(Why? I'm trying to find the oldest and newest documents that match my search criteria.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do 2 queries - one sorted by date ascending and the other sorted by date descending. On each of the queries, limit the result to 1. If the date field is indexed that should be a pretty quick query.

Comment: Much appreciated! One for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since `count` and `skip` are expensive, I believe it's your best bet to perform two queries with different sort order. There's an additional roundtrip, but indexed queries with a `limit` are really quick.

Touching old data very often can be a problem because it forces mongo to keep old stuff in memory. You might want to cache these oldest results if they are somewhat stable and the total amount of data is large. But if your query patterns are complex, caching won't help much either I guess.